# How to retrieve only the similar object from an post api response in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, http-post, parameter-passing

The thing I want is that I have an POST API with end point api/v1/bank/search this gives me all the banks which are saved in my MongoDB.

**This is my bankController code of backend its in java spring**

```
@PostMapping("/search")
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<Wrapper<List<BankDTO>>> searchBanks(@RequestBody BankSearchDTO bankSearchDTO) {
    log.info("Post Mapping Search Bank");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Wrapper.wrap(bankService.searchBanks(bankSearchDTO)));
  }
```

**This is th BankService in spring**

```
  // Returning all the existing banks
  public List<BankDTO> searchBanks(BankSearchDTO bankSearchDTO) {
    log.info("Searching Bank");
    return bankRepository.findAll().stream().map(bankTranslator::toDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

**Now the thing I want is that I have my front end in angular and when I am calling this API front service.ts file in angular the thing is that It loads all the banks in the UI due to which in future there will be more load on UI**

```
public getSearchBank(
   
    address : string,
  city : string,
   
    bankId: string,
    bankName: string,
    branch: string,
    ifscCode: string,
     passBookNo : string
    ){
const postData : Create = {
  ifscCode: ifscCode,
  address: '',
  city : '',
  bankId: '',
  bankName: '',
  branch: '',
  passBookNo: ''
}
{
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/bank/search',postData)
.subscribe((responseData)=>
{

  console.log(responseData);
}
```

***So Is there any way Like I can get only the bank which matches my IFSCCode or like is there any way I can filter the response while calling this post API.***

***By using parameters or something btw I cannot change the API endpoint .***

Answer (score 0):

You need rxjs library and their pipe operators to filter the stream.

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:9900/api/v1/bank/search',postData).pipe(filter(data => data.IFSCode === 12))
.subscribe((responseData)=>
{

  console.log(responseData);
}
```

Comment: .pipe(filter(data => 
  {var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
 res.ifscCode === localStorage.getItem("bankIFSCvalue")
 console.log("PIPE MAP OPERATOR CALLED!!!")
    console.log(res.ifscCode);
}))

When I am adding this pipe mathod it is giving me error as :  No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: Object, index: number) => value is Object, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<Object, Object>', gave the following error.   I have to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)) to access my ifscCode in responseBody . Now what should I do ??

Comment: your function inside the `filter` function has to match the signature. You are supposed to be returning a boolean from it.